# Android. Facebook LikeView. Page like permission

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like, android-facebook

When I click on the LikeView, a confirmation screen appears. I see a banner with "beta" label. Facebook says that it is necessary to approve the use of  the native like button. How can I do this? What permissions do I need to send to Facebook for page liking via LikeView?

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I think you might be having problems setting up the facebook likeview. Please refer to this [tutorial](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-add-facebook-like-button-in-android-app/en), this might help you with your problem.

Comment: Thanks! It's very consistent tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

According to mangu23's answer there is "brief retelling" from this [tutorial](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-add-facebook-like-button-in-android-app/en)

By default LikeView works only with Facebook app's administrator. That is your facebook developer account. To make LikeView works for everyone, you need to send a submission to Facebook team.

1. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/
2. Select app from "**My applications**" popup list
3. Click on "**App review**" (**App Details** in tutorial) left menu item
4. Press "**Start a Submission**" in "**Submit Items for Approval**" section
5. Select "**Native Like Button**" in the end of list
6. Provide step-by-step instructions how Native Like Button works in your app ( desirable with screenshots) and notes.

Additional resources:
[how to submit](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit)